# Time complexity of array method within for-loop

Tags: javascript, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I have an array of names as well as a user input string. I'm trying to build a filter to narrow down the list of names by the input. I believe the current time complexity is O(n2) because of the .includes within the for-loop. I want to see if the current user input is within each name of the array and filter out those that match. How can I do this more efficiently?

My code is currently:

```
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      const currName = names[i];
      if (currName.includes(userInput)) {
        arr.push(currName);
      }
    }
```

Comment: No, this is not O(n^2) since `currName.includes(userInput)` does not depend on the number of names but the length of name itself. If anything this is O(n*m) but if the number of names dominate the length of the names, e.g. each name is at max 20 chars long but you have 1000 of those this is simply O(n).

Comment: Why not just do `if (names.includes(userInput)) {arr.push(userInput)}`? This would be a simple O(n) if I understood your task correctly.

Comment: @luk2302 Don't we assume the worst possible scenario? You're right, the names length will usually not be longer than 20 characters and the list of names is in the thousands.

Comment: @pavel names is an array of strings and in this function, I'm checking for a sub-string within each string in the array. Your answer would not pass this?

Comment: That depends on your data. Actually it depends on the length of `userInput` as well as the implementation of includes. But it certainly wont be O(n^2).

Comment: Ah, ok. Your question didn't say that you're looking for a substring. In that case what you're doing now is fine.

Comment: To speed this up in any way, do `for (let i = 0, n= names.length; i<n;  i++) {` but otherwise it is the fastest method

Comment: @mplungjan No performance to be gained there, the idiomatic version is optimised just fine by modern js engines.

Comment: @Bergi - If not not, but the for loop is the fastest of the methods to iterate an array.